# Params in requests (python)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following url:

```
url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=KEY_VALUE&q=48.85,2.35&num_of_days=2&tp=3&format=json'
```

which I want to access using `requests` `Python` library. If I insert this as the url, it does return the expected data (`requests.get(url)`). My problem arises when trying to connect using the `params` parameter. My approach was the following one:

```
urlPrefix = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx'
parameters = {'key': key, 'q': {48.85,2.35}, 'num_of_days':2, 'tp': 3, 'format': 'json'}

print(requests.get(urlPrefix, params=parameters).url)
>>> http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=KEY_VALYE&tp=3&q=48.85&q=2.35&format=json&num_of_days=2
```

As you can see, the url will vary due to the representation of `{48.85,2.35}`.
Therefore, my question is: how should `q` value represented in order to have the same url request as in the first request?

Answer (score 0):

For the q representation it would be best to group the entire thing as a string.
i.e. `'q':{'48.85,2.35'}`

Comment: @AlvaroGomez That shouldn't raise an issue. The `%2C` inclusion is because of [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and the API like WorldWeatherOnline should already be interpreting it as a `,` for you. Does the actual request work in the way you want with Seekheart's suggestion, or no?